# compile time indexer for enum classes

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

how would you create a kind of compile time indexer that given a group of enum classes is able to correctly create a unique identifier.

```
Template<class... Args>
struct Indexer
{

template<class T>
Indexer(T value)
  {
  value_ = someconstexprfunction<T>(value, interDistance_);
  }

int enumInternalIndexCode() { /* ... */ };
int effectiveEnumCode() { /* ... */  }

static constexpr int enumDistance_ = 100;
int value_ = 0;
};

// Usage:
enum class A {a,b,c,d,e}; enum class B{ a1,b1,c1}; enum class C{z,y,q};
using MyIndexer = Indexer<A,B,C>;
MyIndexer(A::a) t1; // value_ == 0
MyIndexer(B::a1) t2; //value_ ==  100
MyIndexer(B::b1) t3; //value_ ==  101
MyIndexer(C::z) t4; //value_ ==  200
t4.effectiveEnumCode(); // returns 0 (first element of the enum)
t4.enumInternalIndexCode(); // returns 2 (third enum in the Arg list (0,1,2) )
```

Ideally this should be able to work, or at least execute the hashing computations at compile time and even more ideally it should work in C++11. Is this feasible? thanks!

Comment: `effectiveEnumCode` is not possible, all you can get is the enumerator value itself.

Comment: why not? I know it can be get if I use extra memory and save it at construction time, but the ideal is to have just the value_ in this struct.. perhaps using external traits with the enum size info?

Comment: Probably [best what you can get](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c99a58b56928a029)

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant using the extra variables, thank you to make it explicit. There must be some other way.. we just have to discoverer it eheh

Comment: Like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c1e0ace8dbc1142) ?

Comment: Damn it seems working, I'll try with my compiler

Comment: wow it works, thank you! it was so simple.. my only question is this: are the / and % computed at compile time? If that's the case it probably is saving the values anyway I think

Comment: Only if the object is `constexpr`

Comment: Interesting. Now that I'm thinking about it, even in the best case, the results will be saved as compile time constants probably. So we're back to the initial problem, I think there's no solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Index;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Index<T, T, Ts...>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Index<T, U, Ts...>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + Index<T, Ts...>::value> {};

template <typename... Args>
class Indexer
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    constexpr Indexer(T value)
        : _value(Index<T, Args...>::value * _enumDistance + static_cast<int>(value)) {}

    constexpr int enumInternalIndexCode() const { return _value / _enumDistance; }
    constexpr int effectiveEnumCode() const { return _value % _enumDistance; }
    constexpr int value() const { return _value; }

private:
    static constexpr int _enumDistance = 100;
    int _value = 0;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/103865021a3b6253)

Note, however, that this returns the enumerator *value* itself as an effective code.

Comment: can I ask you what exactly do you mean about enumator value itself?

Comment: `enum e { a, b = 2 }`, here for `b` you probably want `1`, while the code returns `2`

Comment: in my case I just needed 2 since I want to convert back to the specific enum value in the future

Comment: then it's not a problem for you